# Rails4 and Bootstrap: responsive design doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Although I tried the code below, these contents are arranged in tandem like this;

```
side1
.
.
.
contents from yield
.
.
.
side2
```

How can I display like this?

```
side1... contents from yield... side2
```

On the other hand, `class="table table-striped"` works, for example.

I have been tried to modify the source created by others.
It would be appreciated if you could give me where I should check.

application.html.erb

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">side1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div><%= notice %></div>
        <div><%= alert %></div>

        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">side2</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Although I tried `col-xs`, I found the same result.

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
```

application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if custom.css.scss has been added to application.css.scss and that application.css is loaded in the layout page?

EDIT:

According to this for the bootstrap version: [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), perhaps you should use `<div class="span4"></div>` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Ho Man. I don't have application.css.scss. Is application.css.scss nesessary? I updated my application.css (not .scss).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Ho Man. Although I added application.css.scss and tried the both, didn't work.

Comment: Looking at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem it seems that perhaps you should use the old syntax of `span3` `span6` etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ho Man. It works! It would be appreciated if you advise me on how to apply `col-sm` or helpful site.

Comment: You'll need to upgrade the boostrap gem version in the Gemfile. Currently it is already at 3.3.6 according to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Thanks again, @Ho Man. It works after upgrading bootstrap 3.